# rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake, abort

I seem to have run into a problem with my database. I have been using Rails to create a website and I have a database for Users. There was a change I needed to make so I rake db:drop and now I see this error:

[database issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gGdq.png)

Here is my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :phone_number, :address_one, :address_two, :city, :country, :state, :zip)
    end
end
```

my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, presence: true

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.id).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.password = "a"
      user.email = user.uid
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

and my current users database table

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.string :phone_number
      t.string :address_one
      t.string :address_two
      t.string :city
      t.string :country
      t.string :state
      t.string :zip
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for the any advice or help given!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The migration filename and class name should be same. The two need to be consistent for rails to dynamically load the appropriate class.

`class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration` change it to `class Users < ActiveRecord::Migration`

Run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: What is your migration filename?

Comment: 20160308001912_users.rb this is my filename

Comment: But you named your migration class name `class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration`. How it will work then? Change it to `class Users < ActiveRecord::Migration`

Comment: Please give the upvote if you like the answer. Thank you